# Как добавить через google script в гугл-таблицу текущую дату в 1 графу всех строках, в которые другой скрипт выгружает массив скопированных строк

Tags: массивы, google-apps-script

Делаю первые шаги в Google Script. Изначально стояла задача добавить автоматическое добавление даты в каждую изменяемую строку. Решил задачу вот таким скриптом:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var str = e.range.getRow();
  var stolb = e.range.getColumn();
      if (stolb == 2 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Архив"&&e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(str,1).getValue()==""){
       e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(str,1).setValue(new Date());
     }
```

Теперь данные вводятся не вручную, а добавляется массив строк (разное количество), скопированный из другой таблицы. Первый скрипт теперь не работает, так как настроен на ручное изменение ячейки.
Подскажите, как добавить в скрипт условие, при котором к массиву скопированных строк будет добавляться также и массив из текущей даты, равный количеству добавляемых строк.
Ниже текст скрипта, копирующего строки:

```
function SaveRows() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  let sVoron = ss.getSheetByName('Воронка')
  let VoronRange = sVoron.getRange('B2:v').getValues()
  let sArchive = ss.getSheetByName('Архив')
  let pushNew =[]
   for (var i in VoronRange) {
    if(VoronRange[i][12] !='' || VoronRange[i][13] !='' && VoronRange[i][16] !=''){
      pushNew.push(VoronRange[i])
      }
  }
    
  let LrArchive = sArchive.getLastRow()
  sArchive.getRange(LrArchive+1,2,pushNew.length,pushNew[0].length).setValues(pushNew)
}
```